# How can I set initial position for slidable_button

Tags: flutter, slider

I'd like to use `slidable_button` found [here](https://pub.dev/packages/slidable_button) to set a bar happy hour on or off in my app. It doesn't have an initial position so I need to use two buttons, one to set happy hour on and another to turn it off. Ideally I'd like to have it initialize in either the left position or the right position depending on the current state. Unfortunately the package is very new and the author is not contactable.

Is there a way I could modify this code to set an initial button position left or right?

Here is the code I have so far. I have two buttons in separate rows in a column but have only shown the code for one as they are similar.

```
           Center(
 
             child: SlidableButton(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
                      buttonWidth: 60.0,
                      color: Colors.green,
                      buttonColor: Colors.blue,
                      dismissible: true,
                      label: Center(child: Text(_user.turnOnString!)),
                      child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text(''),
                            Text('Start'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      onChanged: (position) {
                        if (position == SlidableButtonPosition.right) {_startHappyHour(context, _user);} 
                      },
                    ),

           ),
```

Answer (score 0):

[switch button](https://pub.dev/packages?q=switch%20button) would be more suitable for your situation, like [lite_rolling_switch](https://pub.dev/packages/lite_rolling_switch), you can set initial value(on/off):

```
LiteRollingSwitch(
    //initial value
    value: true,
    textOn: 'disponible',
    textOff: 'ocupado',
    colorOn: Colors.greenAccent[700],
    colorOff: Colors.redAccent[700],
    iconOn: Icons.done,
    iconOff: Icons.remove_circle_outline,
    textSize: 16.0,
    onChanged: (bool state) {
      //Use it to manage the different states
      print('Current State of SWITCH IS: $state');
    },
),
```

Comment: I does look like what I need but it isn't maintained and doesn't state that it is null safe. I would want to change the size for different devices which it says it doesn't support.

Comment: what i suggest is fork the source and modify it to null safety if it's the right one for you, it looks like a simple code, https://github.com/cgustav/lite_rolling_switch/blob/master/lib/lite_rolling_switch.dart